# Failed to import tensorflow in python in Linux using pip3

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used pip3 to install tensorflow.. And after installation, I can find it in

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Besides， I use pip3 list and find it on the list:

```
vincent@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow$ pip3 list
backports.weakref (1.0rc1)
bleach (1.5.0)
html5lib (0.9999999)
Markdown (2.6.8)
numpy (1.13.1)
pip (9.0.1)
protobuf (3.3.0)
setuptools (28.8.0)
six (1.10.0)
tensorflow (1.2.1)
Werkzeug (0.12.2)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

But but I failed to import it in python3.6

```
vincent@ubuntu:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow$ python
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
>>>
```

What's wrong with it?
I ran it in Linux14.04(x64) in VMware

Comment: `>python3` prompt would help. since you are working with `python3`

Comment: @IshantMrinal Yep, I tried. But failed.

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple versions of `python` installed. You can do the following to ensure that `tensorflow` is installed for the version you are using -

```
python -mpip install tensorflow
```

Here I assume that you are using `python` prompt to run python. If you are using a different prompt just use that in place of `python`.

Comment: Yes,I've installed python3.4 and python3. Should I remove python3.4 first?

Comment: Did you try doing the above?

Comment: I tried `sudo python3.6 -mpip install tensorflow`, and it said `The directory '/home/vincent/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
`

Comment: try removing one of the python versions from path, installing tensorflow, than adding your other python it to the path again. also make sure you are doing this as admin

Comment: It seems you can not install libraries for python. What exactly are you using here?

Comment: Finally  I chose to remove python3.6 and this way worked out fine

Comment: I have Python 3.6.12 and pip3.6 list also shows tensorflow 2.4.1, but python -c "import tensorflow" fails with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'.